# Checking if a char isn't equal to the first 6 letters of the alphabet

Tags: java, if-statement, char

Hello I am trying to come up with a solution, to find if my char variable is one of the first six letters of the alphabet. If it is not then its true.

't' is my char variable, which contains a certain unknown value.

What I have:

```
(t < 'a' || t > 'f' && t < 'A' || t > 'F')
```

Comment: so what do you want now?

Comment: Be careful with order of operations.  && binds more tightly than ||.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html `&&` operator has higher precedence than `||` so your condition

```
(t < 'a' || t > 'f' && t < 'A' || t > 'F')
```

is the same as

```
(t < 'a' || (t > 'f' && t < 'A') || t > 'F')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

where you probably want to split in in these parts

```
((t < 'a' || t > 'f') && (t < 'A' || t > 'F'))
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

You can also make your character lower case with `char tLower = Character.toLowerCase(t)` and just check if `tLower < 'a' || tLower > 'f'`.

Answer (score 3):

```
  "ABCDEFabcdef".indexOf(t) != -1
```

Answer (score 1):

your condition is a bit wrong, u meant

```
((t >= 'g' && t <= 'z') || (t >= 'G' && t <= 'Z'))
```

this condition say:

t is bigger or equal 'g' and smaller or equal 'z' **or**

t is bigger or equal 'g' and smaller or equal 'Z'

your condition said

t is smaller then 'a' **or**

bigger then 'f' and t is smaller then 'A' **or**

bigger then 'F'

so every character, including numbers characters and signs could pass the condition

also, when using an `if` statement with `&&` and `||` use the "(" and ")" and explain which parts are seperated

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I shouldn't be one of the first six letters of the alphabet

Comment: @DaViDa haha, let me edit it. wait, is it still need to be a letter?

Comment: Given  a char variable   t that has already  been given  a value , write an expression  whose value  is true  if and only if  t is NOT one of the first six letters in the alphabet. (I need to use a and f)

Comment: @DaViDa it isn't clear, but  believe that they are talking on alphabet chaacters

Comment: @DaViDa then accept his answer :) anyway his answer also let signs in, so make sure that signs like '@' are accepable

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
string toCheck = 'b';

for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  if(toCheck.equal(array[i]) {
     //oh crap
  }
  else //we are in home
}
```

Comment: haha i liked the "oh crap" part, but unfortunately the condition isn't good

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
((t >= 'a' && t <= 'f') || (t >= 'A' && t <= 'F'))
```

evaluates to `true` if the letter is between A and F (uppercase or lowercase).

You want it to evaluate to `true` if this **isn't** the case, so

```
!((t >= 'a' && t <= 'f') || (t >= 'A' && t <= 'F'))
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some lengthy implementation, for understanding purposes you can try this with JDK 1.7.

```
 char t='t';
    boolean status=true;
    switch (String.valueOf(t).toLowerCase())
    {
        case "a": status=false;
            break;
        case "b": status=false;
            break;
        case "c": status=false;
            break;
        case "d": status=false;
            break;
        case "e": status=false;
            break;
        case "f": status=false;
            break;
    }
    if(status){
        System.out.println("condition satisfied");
    }else{
        System.out.println("letter is "+String.valueOf(t)+" and it is between a and f");
    }
```